# R - eliminating duplicate values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have an input dataframe like this:

[image]

I want the output to be like this:

[image]

For example, I want to take up the first value(mary has life), scan it against all other rows which have duplicate COL1 entries and if a duplicate COL2 value is present I need to eliminate duplicates alone while merging non-duplicates.  In other words, I want to do pattern search. If the same pattern is present in another row, I just want to eliminate duplicate patterns and merge non-duplicate patterns.

I tried using the grepl and gsub functions but I am not able to get my desired result properly.

**Inserting a simpler version of input dataset below:**

COL1    COL2
10  mary has life
10  Don mary has life
10  Britto mary has life
20  push them
20  push them fur
30  yell at this
30  this is yell at this
40  Year
40  Doggy
40  Horse

Comment: please when adding some code (or data example like this) indent with 4 blank spaces, so it becomes more readable, or use dput(mydf)

Comment: I deleted my answer because apparently I do not understand the way you want it handled.

Comment: You want to get set of unique space separated patterns without separating strings? That doesn't really make sense... Or I still don't understand your restrictions to the solution.

Comment: I edited the post so that it makes sense now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your update:

```
df <- read.table(
  text = "COL1;    COL2
10;  mary has life
10;  Don mary has life
10;  Britto mary has life
20;  push them
20;  push them fur
30;  yell at this
30;  this is yell at this", 
  sep = ";", header = TRUE, 
  strip.white = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>%
  do(COL2 = {
    first_value <- .$COL2[[1]]
    paste(unlist(Reduce(function(a, b) {
      new_values <- strsplit(b, first_value)[[1]]
      c(a, new_values)
    }, .$COL2)), collapse = ", ")
  })
res$COL2 <- unlist(res$COL2)
```

Comment: This piece of code works just fine...But there should be a small correction in this......Say for example, in my input above, if I change all the COL2 values to unique values i.e (Mary, Don, Britto, push, fur, yell, this)..... Then for the first row in output I should be getting (Mary, Don, Britto).... For the 2nd row in output I should be getting (push, fur)... and for the 3rd row in output I should be getting (yell, this).....In simple words, your code is not working if COL2 values contain unique single words in which case the unique words should be merged together

Comment: I simply removed `if (new_values[1] == b) new_values <- NULL`. Be careful: like you said, it works *just* fine, not more than *just*. There are a lot of assumptions regarding your input data in this. Maybe there are simpler ways to your end goal, that require less brittle code.

Comment: Now this is working fine... But it is not working for my original input... @Apom .. I have edited my question now... if the code works fine for this input, I'm done with my hardship... Could u pls assist

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the output of this script? Like I said, maybe there are simpler ways if you rethink your problem

Comment: For duplicate COL1 rows in the input, I want to merge all unique text patterns of each row... The duplicate entries should be discarded... The code u provided at first was perfect..except that it did not work if I had all unique COL2 entries in the duplicate rows, where I would expect all the unique entries to be merged in the output

Comment: Seems to work now. What is wrong with the current output? Looks like what is expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126135/discussion-between-apom-and-rambo).